# Horizontal axis tick marks

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have a question about adjusting the number of horizontal tick marks on a 2D plot.

Example:

```
f[x_] := 4*Sin[4*x]

Plot[{f[x]}, {x, -10, 10}, Ticks -> {Table[Pi n, {n, -5, 5}]}]
```

Gives the following plot:

[image]

How would I go about adding more ticks so I could change the range (in terms of $\pi$) to fractional values of $\pi$?

Say $-\pi/10$ to $\pi/10$.

or...in increments of $\pi/2$....or $\pi/4$?

The `Plot` command I am using is one I found from the *help* because I couldn't figure out how to make the ticks in terms of $\pi$. I'm still learning some of the basics, but I'm quite stuck on changing the number of ticks.

Anyone have some ideas please?

Comment: Take a look at `Table[Pi n, {n, -5, 5}]`.  What does it output?  What do you need to change to have multiples of `Pi/2`?

Comment: To be honest I don't know what it does. I thought it merely set the number of labels that show on the 'x-axis', but per your post, which I just did not think of, changing those values to -5/2 and 5/2 gives what I'm looking for. Is there an easier ay to accomplish this however?

Comment: Then please start by reading up on `Table` and understanding what it does and how to use it.  Use the documentation.  Table is one of the most fundamental constructs in Mathematica and it is quite easy to understand.

Comment: Yes, for sure. Up to now it had not come up, but I will look the documentation. Now, your having said that, I asked if there were any other ways to accomplish this task. Is this just one way of doing it, or the easiest? Insight?

Comment: Yes, it's the easiest.  For more complex tick arrangements the [CustomTicks package](http://scidraw.nd.edu/CustomTicksGuide.pdf) is easier, but not for simple ones like what you described.

Comment: Okay, so what I'm using is the most straightforward, but the other option is this advanced package (thank you for sending along by the way). Well, this should keep me out of trouble for a while. I appreciate the time and help.  :)

Comment: I know I'm suppose to choose a best answer on here, but I have no idea how or where that is suppose to be done. I also was given some kind of notice that 'commenting' isn't preferred either, but I didn't see any other way to respond to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[4*Sin[4*x], {x, -10, 10}, 
Ticks -> {Table[Pi/2 n, {n, -15, 15}], Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you santosh. I see what you have done. I thought I tried that and got an error, but I like your method. I will look at it again.